# How to get table of "0" in php

Tags: php, html

This PHP Code show the tables 1 TO 10 only. But I need 0 TO 10. When i put the 0 in input filed it display "Invalid Entry" Please help me. Here is code. What changing are required in this code.

```
<?php

       $num = $_POST['num'];
       if($num)
       {
       for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)

       {

        $mul = $num * $i;
        echo "$num * $i = $mul";

       }

      }
   else
   {

    echo "Invalid Entry!";

   }
  ?>
```

Comment: Then start with 0. `for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)`

Comment: You should start loop from *0*

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is with the if statement since it is executing the else part. In the case $num == 0 the for loop is never reached.

Answer (score 3):

It is because when $num is zero it is equivalent to logical false. Thus your if statement fails. Try

```
if (is_numeric($num))
```

instead.

Comment: Brave and correct! I upvoted your answer, the injustice!

Comment: No, if the input is `1` it will again say invalid. As per the question the output would be I guess - `1*0=0`, `1*1 = 1` and so on.

Comment: You are correct, the appropriate function is is_numeric() as suggested by Nick before someone voted down his correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
<?php

       $num = $_POST['num'];
       if(isset($num) && $num>=0)
       {
       for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)

       {

        $mul = $num * $i;
        echo "$num * $i = $mul";

       }

      }
   else
   {

    echo "Invalid Entry!";

   }
  ?>
```

Comment: You should add check if the input is digit or not.